# Parallax scrolling effect isn't working well with background-size: contain

Tags: html, css, parallax, background-size

Couldn't find a single thing in regards to this using a Google search, so here I am, really hoping someone can tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Here is the CSS:

```
.section {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.section.blue {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #0085ca;
}

.section.blue {
    color: #FFF;
}

.section .parallax-img {
    padding-bottom: 52%;
    position: relative;
  background-size: contain;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: top;
}

.section-content {
    padding: 3em 1em;
    max-width: 850px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.section-content.center {
    text-align: center;
}

.section p {
    font: normal 400 1em/1.375em "jaf-bernina-sans-n4", "jaf-bernina-sans", Arial, Helvetica;
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}

.section a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.section a:hover {
    color: #B20000;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.section a.button {
    margin-top: 2em;
}

.section ul {
    list-style: square outside;
    margin: 0 0 1.5em 1.125em;
    padding: 0;
}

.section ul li {
    line-height: 1.375em;
    margin-bottom: 0.125em;
}

.section ol {
    list-style: decimal outside;
    margin: 0 0 1.5em 1.125em;
    padding: 0;
}

.section ol li {
    line-height: 1.375em;
    margin-bottom: 0.125em;
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="page-container">


                    <div class="section blue">


                            <div class="parallax-img" style="background-image: url(http://dev.lakinmilling.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/feed-bags.jpg);" data-rjs="2"></div>


                            <div class="section-content center">

                    <p><span class="intro-quote">&#8220;For Good Horsekeeping Since 1960&#8221;</span><br />
Lakin Milling company pioneered high quality, nutritionally complete, pelleted horse feed in the Southwest, after Chuck Laken introduced the concept in 1960.</p>


                </div>
            </div>



                    <div class="section">

                            <div class="parallax-img" style="background-image: url(http://dev.lakinmilling.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/horses.jpg);" data-rjs="2"></div>

                            <div class="section-content">


                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec et venenatis massa. Phasellus ultrices lobortis fringilla. Integer consectetur gravida lectus vel iaculis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Vestibulum suscipit ex eu libero suscipit pharetra. Donec ut justo laoreet, vehicula enim ac, condimentum turpis. Pellentesque quis tortor non enim placerat consequat. Praesent lacinia nisi nibh, a consectetur mi laoreet et.</p>


                </div>
            </div>



                    <div class="section">

                            <div class="parallax-img" style="background-image: url(http://dev.lakinmilling.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/feed-bags.jpg);" data-rjs="2"></div>

                            <div class="section-content">


                    <p><strong>Highest Quality—and Nutritionally Complete</strong><br />
Donec mattis elementum libero. Suspendisse luctus porta ipsum, in tristique justo tincidunt nec. Maecenas non aliquam orci. Aliquam tempus dolor in quam tempor, sed dictum orci scelerisque. Fusce ut lectus urna. Aliquam ac libero tincidunt tellus tempus fringilla. Etiam condimentum, mi ut finibus lobortis, quam nunc imperdiet nunc, id fermentum massa lectus in quam.</p>
<div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 4em;">
<img src="http://dev.lakinmilling.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/KER-logo.jpg" alt="KER Logo" width="284" height="159" />
</div>


                </div>
            </div>


                    <div class="section blue">




                            <div class="section-content center">

                    <p>&#8220;Nunc blandit orci sed nunc cursus, in finibus orci tristique. Praesent eget justo sit amet urna eleifend euismod ut sit amet lacus. Proin at posuere dolor. Morbi at justo sit amet odio accumsan imperdiet. Morbi quis nibh ligula.&#8221;</p>
<p>Linda Colica<br />
The Tucson Equestrian Center, Tucson Arizona<</p>

                                            <a class="button" href="http://dev.lakinmilling.com/products/">View Our Products</a>

                </div>
            </div>


</div>
```

I made a JS Fiddle to showcase the issue I am having:
https://jsfiddle.net/5bk5sdt9/

Notice that when you scroll down, you do get the parallax effect, but there is a large white gap under each parallax image before you reach the content.

Change "background-size: contain" to "background-size: cover", and the issue is solved (but then the images don't contain themselves the way I want them to).

So my question is, what am I doing wrong here? I'm shocked that I couldn't find anything on this subject with a Google search.

Comment: Try to use a background image that has a bigger height than your container element.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: The container element doesn't have a specified height though.

Comment: Use an image from this site: placeholder.com. Play around with the height and width so you will have an idea how contain works.